# Angular - How to mock wrapper component with Jest and NgMocks

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

In our project we can assign user roles to multiple elements throughout the application which disable the elements when the required role is missing. But since for some buttons other conditions are applied, which may also disabled the component even if the role checks, our component also takes it over and disables its child if necessary. The reason behind this design that we can easily display tooltips if the element should be disabled.

```
// app-role-element
<div matTooltip="{{ tooltipMessage | translate }}" [matTooltipDisabled]="!isDisabled">
  <ng-content> </ng-content>
</div>
// .ts
export class AppRoleElement implements AfterConentInit {
  @Input('roles') roles: string[];
  @ContentChild('roleElement') roleElement: MatButton;

  constructor(...){}    

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    ...
    this.setDisabled();
  }

  setDisabled(): void {
    if (this.roleElement) {
      if (this.isDisabled) {
        this.roleElement.disabled = true; // disable if no role
      } else {
        this.roleElement.disabled = this.disableCondition; // disable if other condition
      }
    }
  }
}

// usage
<app-role-component
  [role]="['required-role']"
  [disableCondition]= "isRunning || isUnstable"
  [id]="startButtonRoleElem"
>
  <button mat-raised-button id="startBtnId" (click)="start()">Start</button>
</app-role-component>
```

This approach works fine but it's difficult to unit test. In the code above, if I'm to write a unit test where I click on the Start button, selecting it by ID bypasses the role-element and calls the remote service even if it shouldn't. Selecting the role element by ID does not propagate the click on the button.

```
test('to prevent click on a start btn when form is invalid', () => {
  spectator.component.runEnabled$ = of(false);
  spectator.detectComponentChanges();

  const checkExportFolderSpy = jest.spyOn(spectator.component, 'checkExportFolder');
  spectator.inject(PreferencesService).validateCurrentExportPath.andReturn(of(VALIDATION_RESULT_OK));
  spectator.detectChanges();

  spectator.click('#startBtnId');
  spectator.detectChanges();

  expect(checkExportFolderSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(dispatchSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

We're using JEST together with Spectator and NgMocks and I was hoping to leverage that functionality and mock this component, but I have no idea how. And I'm not really sure to what extend should I try to mock it, should I pass the click event to child, disable child? Any idea or recommendations how to deal with this?

Comment: Might you create an example on stackblitz with the desired test which fails? As I understand you want to check whether the disabled button doesn't trigger effects on "click". Is it right? Then I would say you should mock everything, except `AppRoleElement`. And simply assert whether `triggerEventHandler` for clicks calls the spied `start`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve. Click on the button but this should not happen as the `app-role-element` should disable it. I'll give it a try with your suggestion. And about stackblitz, I need to find out if I can actually make it work with all the test dependencies that are necessary

Comment: Got it, later today I'll try to solve it to and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is a complicated one.

It is complicated because:

- the button is disabled via `MatButton`, therefore it cannot be mocked
- because we want to test `AppRoleElement`, it also cannot be mocked
- `triggerEventHandler` doesn't respect `disabled` attribute and always triggers clicks

Therefore in the test we need:

- keep `AppRoleElement` and `MatButton` as they are
- create a special environment for the disabled and enabled cases
- click button via `nativeElement`

The code below uses only [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) and role detection has been simplified.

```js
import {AfterContentInit, Component, ContentChild, Input, NgModule,} from '@angular/core';
import {MatButton, MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MockBuilder, MockRender, ngMocks} from 'ng-mocks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-role-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
})
class AppRoleElement implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() public disable: boolean | null = null;
  @ContentChild(MatButton) public roleElement?: MatButton;

  public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.setDisabled();
  }

  public setDisabled(): void {
    if (this.roleElement) {
      this.roleElement.disabled = this.disable;
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppRoleElement],
  imports: [MatButtonModule],
})
class AppModule {}

fdescribe('ng-mocks-click', () => {
  // Keeping AppRoleElement and MatButton
  beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(AppRoleElement, AppModule).keep(MatButton));

  it('is not able to click the disabled button', () => {
    // specific params for the render
    const params = {
      disabled: true,
      start: jasmine.createSpy('start'),
    };

    // rendering custom template
    MockRender(
      `
      <app-role-component
        [disable]="disabled"
      >
        <button mat-raised-button id="startBtnId" (click)="start()">Start</button>
      </app-role-component>
    `,
      params,
    );

    // click on a disable element isn't propagandized
    ngMocks.find('button').nativeElement.click();

    // asserting
    expect(params.start).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  // checking the enabled case
  it('is able to click the button', () => {
    const params = {
      disabled: false,
      start: jasmine.createSpy('start'),
    };

    MockRender(
      `
      <app-role-component
        [disable]="disabled"
      >
        <button mat-raised-button id="startBtnId" (click)="start()">Start</button>
      </app-role-component>
    `,
      params,
    );

    ngMocks.find('button').nativeElement.click();
    expect(params.start).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```